# Plotting fitted glm output using ggplot2 for interactions

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, interaction, data-fitting

I am trying to plot my model output for two different models using `ggplot2`. When I visualize my plots they look exactly the same despite that they are fitted.

The only difference between the two models is the addition of a variable "age" to the second model (and all two-way interactions that include "age").

The first model is as follows:

```
ab_bi_f= glm(LRS_Bin ~ as.factor(DispersalFate) + MastN + as.factor(DispersalFate)*MastN, data = female, family = binomial(link = logit))
```

The second model is as follows:

```
rel_bi_f = glm(LRS_Bin ~ as.factor(DispersalFate) + Age + MastN + as.factor(DispersalFate)*MastN + Age*MastN +as.factor(DispersalFate)*Age, data = female, family = binomial(link = logit))
```

The code I use to fit and visualize the first models is:

```
fitted1<- function (fit) {
    ggplot(data=fit$ab_bi_f, aes(x=MastN, y=LRS_Bin, colour=factor(DispersalFate))) + 
         stat_smooth() + 
         ggtitle("Binary absolute LRS model - female") + 
         labs(x="Total masts in female's lifespan", y="Mean fitted binary absolute LRS", colour="Dispersal type")+
         scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2))+
         theme_classic()+annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0.89, label = "a",size=6)+
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.1, 0.9))+
         scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9))+
         scale_color_manual(values=c("#000000", "#999999"))+
         theme(legend.position=c(0.3,0.85),
         plot.title = element_text(size = 10),
         legend.title=element_text(size=10),
         axis.title=element_text(size=8), 
         legend.key = element_rect(size = 0.1),
         legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
         legend.direction="horizontal")
}
plot1<-fitted1(glm(MastN~LRS_Bin))
```

And, the code I used to visualize the second model is:

```
fitted2<- function (fit) {
    ggplot(data=fit$rel_bi_f, aes(x=MastN, y=LRS_Bin, colour=factor(DispersalFate))) + 
         stat_smooth() + 
         ggtitle("Binary absolute LRS model - female") + 
         labs(x="Total masts in female's lifespan", y="Mean fitted binary absolute LRS", colour="Dispersal type")+
         scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2))+
         theme_classic()+annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0.89, label = "a",size=6)+
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.1, 0.9))+
         scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9))+
         scale_color_manual(values=c("#000000", "#999999"))+
         theme(legend.position=c(0.3,0.85),
         plot.title = element_text(size = 10),
         legend.title=element_text(size=10),
         axis.title=element_text(size=8), 
         legend.key = element_rect(size = 0.1),
         legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
         legend.direction="horizontal")
}
plot2<-fitted2(glm(MastN~LRS_Bin))
```

This is the resulting plot:
[image]

The two plots look exactly the same!

I can't figure out if I am making a mistake in my code or if the two models (despite the second model being different from the first) result in the same output...

My data and code can be found [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in the code you are using. I am not sure how you are getting the output you have attached. However, if you just want to visualize the fitted values. You can do it as follows:-

```
ab_bi_f= glm(LRS_Bin ~ as.factor(DispersalFate) + MastN + as.factor(DispersalFate)*MastN, data = female, family = binomial(link = logit))

rel_bi_f = glm(LRS_Bin ~ as.factor(DispersalFate) + Age + MastN + as.factor(DispersalFate)*MastN + Age*MastN +as.factor(DispersalFate)*Age, data = female, family = binomial(link = logit))

female$fit1 <- predict(ab_bi_f, type = 'response')
female$fit2 <- predict(rel_bi_f, type = 'response')

plot1 <- ggplot(data=female, aes(x=MastN, y=fit1, colour=factor(DispersalFate))) + 
        geom_point() + 
        stat_smooth() + 
        ggtitle("Binary absolute LRS model - female") + 
        labs(x="Total masts in female's lifespan", y="Mean fitted binary absolute LRS", colour="Dispersal type")+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2))+
        theme_classic()+annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0.89, label = "a",size=6)+
        coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.1, 0.9))+
        scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9))+
        scale_color_manual(values=c("#000000", "#999999"))+
        theme(legend.position=c(0.3,0.85),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.title=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=8), 
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 0.1),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        legend.direction="horizontal")

plot2 <- ggplot(data=female, aes(x=MastN, y=fit2, colour=factor(DispersalFate))) + 
        geom_point() + 
        stat_smooth() + 
        ggtitle("Binary absolute LRS model - female") + 
        labs(x="Total masts in female's lifespan", y="Mean fitted binary absolute LRS", colour="Dispersal type")+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2))+
        theme_classic()+annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0.89, label = "a",size=6)+
        coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.1, 0.9))+
        scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9))+
        scale_color_manual(values=c("#000000", "#999999"))+
        theme(legend.position=c(0.3,0.85),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.title=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=8), 
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 0.1),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        legend.direction="horizontal")

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2)
```

[image: Plot of fitted models]

Comment: Does your plot1 have confidence intervals around the lines like it does in plot2? Using your code, the CIs only show up in the second plot.

Comment: It doesn't. I have edited the plots to include the points. You can see that plot 1 doesn't have enough points to build a confidence interval (ggplot also gives you a warning for the same). This is because of how model 1 is formulated and resulting fitted values.

Comment: Oh, thank you for clarifying that. I did not understand that this was what was going on. Thank you for your help!